# Sample example or tutorial using knockout KoLite for change tracking

Tags: knockout-2.0, kolite

Is there any simple example on how to use knockout kolite to track the changes. 
I saw this link posted by john papa [Kolite][1]. I didnt understood how he is binding changes to the html element for tracking changes. Anyone have any simple example of how to use it then its highly appreciated. I am newbee when it comes to knockout. Please help. Many thanks

I found one example. Here is link to fiddle
[KoLite example](http://jsfiddle.net/ashreva/6dz7g/10/)

In fiddle you can see that save button is hiding and unhiding properly if there are any changes made to input field. I added code to enable the Cancel button but its not working.

```
<div data-bind="enable: dirtyFlag().isDirty">
       <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Please can you tell me why?

Comment: I am extremely struck with implementation of dirty flag. Cant get any direction. Please help me you brilliant guys

Comment: Any examples? I really need this thing to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/6dz7g/12/

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>  

<div data-bind="if: dirtyFlag().isDirty">
    <button>Save</button>
</div>  

<div>
    <button data-bind="enable: dirtyFlag().isDirty">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I've simply used ifnot binding for the save button.

Comment: I need to enable and disable cancel button